# What does "a shot across Lululemon Athletica's bow" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Nike also launched a line of maternity clothing for runners, something Donahoe says is part of the company's work to keep taking market share away from rivals in women's athletic wear. And in a shot across Lululemon Athletica's bow, Nike launched a new line of yoga wear. The company also benefited from its recently revamped Air Max 90 shoe.

Source: https://fortune.com/2020/09/23/nike-q1-ecommerce-results-covid-19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, when one ship wished to warn another to stop doing something objectionable, they would fire a single shot from their cannon so that the cannonball would pass ahead of the second ship - that is, it would fire across the bow (front) of the ship. This is now an idiom that means that the action so characterized is a warning of some sort to the ostensible target.

In this particular example, it means that Lululemon Athletica should take the Nike yoga wear introduction as a warning that Nike is going to challenge Lululemon's dominance in the yoga wear market.

([Collins English Dictionary on **A shot across the bow**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/a-shot-across-the-bow))